# How to create a "Check if" function on SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, designer-workflow, if-condition

I am working on a delegation workflow for approvals.

Is there a 'check if' function on SharePoint for separate lists?

For Example:

Check if `[ListA_Manager]` matches/equal `[ListB_Absent Staff]`

I don't want to make the manager or absent value specific.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function as a single step, but depending on your version of SharePoint Designer, you can use a HTTP request to get items in a list. You could filter the list or loop through all items in absent staff and compare it to the manager name.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response! Will I need to use HTTP request even if ListB and ListA are in the same site collection?